# Vertical line on my monitor, incompatible monitor? Would there be a way to fix that?

Tags: ubuntu, video, graphics-card, hdmi, desktop

I got a new server with an GeForce RTX 2060 from EVGA.

It works great on my 4K TV (although the TV is too "white").

When I try the exact same setup (I unplug the cable from the TV and plug it to my monitor) my [HP 2509m monitor](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01869172), a somewhat old HDTV (1920x1080) monitor which works just fine with my older computer, generates a set of whitish vertical line that "dance" on the monitor.

So far I only tried with an HDMI cable which I had readily available.

Would there be a reason for those vertical lines? They appear at *specific* horizontal positions in blocks of 3 or 4 within an inch or so.

[image]

This is a freeze from a video so the rest of the screen looks like crap too, but in reality it looks just fine on the monitor except for those vertical lines.

I also have [a video](https://youtu.be/kWXyoHwZIGQ), although the quality is awful, it may be easier for you to see what I mean by vertical lines "moving" (the stay at the same horizontal position, but what would look like pixels inside the line goes up or down).

It is pretty small too, when looking at the screen from a distance I don't really see these lines. But to work all day with such would be bad!

Is there something I can do to fix the problem? (outside of getting a new *better* monitor)

Comment: First thing I'd try is to use a different cable. Maybe even VGA, just to see if that works better. And maybe change the screen resolution or frequency.

Comment: Check you're not downscaling/downsampling from 4k to 1080p and that you're in native 1080p

Comment: @Smock, How do I check that? When I go to the Display resolution dialog I used 1920x1080 (and the sync. is 60Hz). Is there something else I can do?

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of [this](https://superuser.com/a/533751/1015063) but unless you set it that way, it's very unlikely to just be set like that. Have you tried the Auto-adjust button on the monitor? (assuming there is one)

Comment: Oh, I have an Auto-Adjustment button. I'll try that and VGA tomorrow. It would be great to keep the same monitor until I finally get a 4K... It's really good quality.

Comment: @Smock, well... I'm not too sure where I saw an auto-adjustment in my monitor settings. I looked again today and saw nothing. I then tried the Auto feature of the nVidia settings to no avail. The vertical lines stuck around.

Comment: @Berend, I tried the DVI port with a DVI to VGA and then connected the VGA cable there. Same thing. So I guess the card & monitor are just not compatible. Sad. I was surprised, though, to see the exact same thing on either port. (I guess it makes sense?)

Comment: Ha! Ha! Ha! Well... I kept the Beaver as the background in my new server just because, and I though, let's download [that beaver's picture](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/03/this-is-the-ubuntu-18-04-default-wallpaper) and try it on my old computer... it does exactly the same thing on either computer/video board. So I'll try again my new computer with a different background to see what happens. But it looks like I've resolved my issue.

Comment: @AlexisWilke - on the actually monitor itself, not in software. There's usually an 'AUTO' button on it. (sometimes you need the OSD up to find it - but again - buttons on the actual monitor)

Comment: @AlexisWilke - it's not something on the actual background image itself is it? does it display across desktop apps too? Is the image the native resolution of the monitor? (ie 1920x1080) ? If it's a 4k image, it will downsample it to display it as a background on 1080p

Comment: @Smock, yes. I'm wondering whether the "auto-adjustment" in my OSD gets hidden when the input is HDMI because I could find it this time and I'm using VGA. However, it did not help. I think the problem is with the gradient. Somehow my old monitor just doesn't like that specific gradient. Since I see the same effect with the old board, I'm not worried anymore.

Comment: @Smock It's in the question. I made it a link now. It's an HP 2509m. It could be that these lines have been there for a while, it's hard to see them when it's on a very small area. I see it now in my gray menu bar at the top. I'd have to restart my X-Windows session to see whether it sticks.

Comment: The Auto button is the [one on the right](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images2500x2500/HP_Hewlett_Packard_NT195AA_ABA_2509m_25_Full_HD_648498.jpg) (closest the power button) labelled Auto / OK. I would imagine you hold it down for 5 seconds or so to auto adjust.

Comment: @Smock, indeed that works too! It looks like I have to hold just 2 or 3 seconds. But anyway, the monitor is always showing those lines. It's just that in a normal environment, there are not very many locations where I see them. Anyway, I guess that means I'll need a new monitor _soon_.